# Why would I check in a Runnable, that its Thread is not null?

Tags: java, runnable

I've found code like this in a project I'm taking over. I'm not sure, what the if condition is supposed to accomplish. If the Runnable is running, it does so in the Thread it checks for being `null`. So that is always the case, right?

```
public class Outer 
{
    Thread m_thread = null;

    public Outer() 
    {
         Runnable runner = new Runnable()
         {
             public void run()
             {
                 if ( m_thread != null )
                     do_stuff();
             }
         };

         m_thread = new Thread(runner);
         m_thread.start();
    }
}
```

There is actually another method, that sets `m_thread` to `null`, but since there is no loop in the runnable, does that make a difference? `do_stuff()` does not access `m_thread`.

Comment: It makes no sense

Comment: Since the `runner` gets used in a `new Thread(runner)` anyway, this `Thread` will never be `null`...

Comment: Is there some code somewhere else that sets `m_thread` to null?

Comment: This looks like you have simplified the code: it's possible there is some relevant detail you have omitted.

Comment: Creating a thread acts as a write/read barrier. If you set a value, it will be visible to any thread started after that by that thread.

Answer (score 2):

Since `m_thread` is not marked `volatile` or guarded by any other memory barrier operation it's possible that when `Runnable` is running it will observe `m_thread` to be `null`. If `do_stuff()` requires non-null reference to `m_thread`, the code will fail.

Check the [Safe Publication and Safe Initialization in Java](https://shipilev.net/blog/2014/safe-public-construction/#_safe_publication) article by Shipilev to understand safe publication idioms in Java. In short:

> There are a few trivial ways to achieve safe publication:
>
> - Exchange the reference through a properly locked field (JLS 17.4.5)
> - Use static initializer to do the initializing stores (JLS 12.4)
> - Exchange the reference via a volatile field (JLS 17.4.5), or as the consequence of this rule, via the AtomicX classes
> - Initialize the value into a final field (JLS 17.5).

Comment: The code won't fail as creating a Thread is a read/write memory barrier.

Answer (score 1):

Simply spoken: that doesn't make any sense. When a line of code is executed in Java, *some* thread is running it.

Unless you start implementing your own *tracking* of threads, the fact that your code is running ... tells it that *some* thread is running it.

The code shown here A) violates Java naming conventions, and it also B) violates "common sense" in Java.

You see, you could still write code that first *initializes* that `m_thread` field, to then invoke `runner.run()` directly from the "main" thread. And the run method would find that the field is not null, and invoke `doStuff()`. If at all, you could check that `Thread.getCurrentThread()` returns something **else** than your "main" thread.

As in:

```
class Outer {
  private Thread mainThread;

  public Outer() 
  {
     mainThread = Thread.getCurrentThread();

     Runnable runner = new Runnable()
     {
         public void run()
         {
             if ( Thread.getCurrentThread() != mainThread )
                 do_stuff();
         }
     };

     m_thread = new Thread(runner);
     m_thread.start();
}
```

( I didn't run the above through the compiler, it is meant as "pseudo code like" example, not necessarily 100% correct )

Answer (score 1):

You don't. There was a fashion 20 years ago, that I think may have originated in a magazine, for `run()` methods to loop `while (Thread.currentThread() != null)`. It was meaningless then and it is meaningless now, even when slightly re-expressed as in your code.